# I can not let my app available on market of honeycomb(xoom)

Tags: google-play

I have an app, and I have changed this app according to tutorial of
google as http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/optimizing-for-3.0.html.

this is my mainfest xml:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <!--uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/-->
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /
>
   <uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
       <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>
   <supports-screens
       android:resizeable="true"
       android:anyDensity="true"
       android:smallScreens="true"
       android:normalScreens="true"
       android:largeScreens="true"
       android:xlargeScreens="true"
   />
.............
...........
```

after I upload it to google market.
I can see it at htc dream, magic, nexus one, desire-z, samsung galaxy
tab.
when I borrow an XOOM to install app. I found I can not see the app,
even if I look for its name or similar words, the result is nothing.

and I have searched for long time, but I can not get answer.
any answer will be appreciated so much!

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I set a minSdkVersion of 7 and a targetSdkVersion of 9, and I'm unable to find my app in the marketplace on a version 11 device

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're having this issue still, but I had the same problem. I had to setup licensing instead of copy protection on the market. You need to add the licensing library and a little code to your project but it's pretty simple, step by step guide is in google's documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html

And also check your uses, phone options will not work on the Xoom I believe, I had maybe 2 permissions and it was driving me nuts why it wouldn't show on the Xoom. Because the Xoom doesn't have sd card support yet it relies on internal storage and because of permissions the copy protection doesn't work so you must use licensing. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

also check that if you are using uses-feature in the manifest that it's supported on the xoom (btw your manifest is not viewable)